# Title com variavel PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, variáveis, seo

Olá, desenvolvi uma page **detalhes.php** que usa o metodo get para pegar as informações dos dados e jogar na página. E coloquei uma variavel **$nome** dentro do title HTML

```
<title><?php echo $nome ?></title>
```

Está funcionando, cada detalhe tem seu title de acordo com o nome, mas tenho a duvida se é o correto e se vai funcionar como mecanismo de busca do google.. Pois ainda não consegui pesquisar nenhum dos nome na busca do google obs: as paginas ainda pegam poucos clicks, e o google analitycs está dando as exibições de cada detalhe..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se ao observar o HTML de seu site e a tag `title` estiver normal, então tudo estará tranquilo para o Google.

Vale lembrar que o Google indexa seu site de acordo com a vontade dele, sem falar que os fatores para ranqueamento são secretos. Logo é seguro dizer que seu site, se for um site novo (menos de um ano) e pouco famoso (poucos backlinks) é difícil achá-lo ao pesquisar na SERP.

O que você pode fazer e pesquisar o titulo entre aspas duplas no Google "meu titulo" dessa forma você força o Google a exibir resultados com as palavras exatas, quem sabe seu seite aparece. Outra forma é usar o operador `site:` como mostrado abaixo, ele mostra tudo que o Google indexou de seu site

```
site:meusite.com
```